# Remove Lines With Number Less Than X In Nth Field

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file consisting of lines like this:

```
ExampleText | En | 1.0
ExampledText | Es | 0.9
ExamplesText | En | 0.9994
ExampleTexts | Br | 0.991
ExampledText | Es | 0.83324
ExamplerText | En | 0.4494
```

Using `grep .*| En`, I can get all the lines containing `En`. However, how can I also remove all values that contain less than 0.5 in the last column?

Thus, the output is:

```
ExampleText | En | 1.0
ExamplesText | En | 0.9994
```

Your positive input is highly appreciated.

Comment: the last line is filtered out. And the 2nd line has `Es` not `En`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thank you. I've noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '$2 == "En" && $3 >= .5' FS=' \\| '
```

1. Set field separator to  `|`
2. Match if field 2 equals `En` and field 3 is greater or equal to `.5`

Comment: Nice explanation :-)